Need help to effectively communicate the value of a simpler, more concise design that aligns with user preferences?
I'm seeking your expertise in resolving a design dilemma. I've created two design options for updating or adding a new qualified worker, and I'd love your input on how to effectively communicate the benefits of the preferred design to our product team.
Scenario: A client needs to update the start date of a pending qualified worker and extend the end date of the current active qualified worker. Also, they can add a new one.
Design1 - Simple Date Field: One field with a clear label, allowing users to click and select the date. (User-tested and preferred)
Design2 - Radio Button Selection: Users select an option (Extend or Remove), leading to a date field with different labels depending on the selection. (Product team's preferred option)
User Feedback: Users prefer Design 1 due to its simplicity, clarity, and reduced clutter. They find the radio button selection in Design 2 unnecessary and cumbersome.
Request for Help: I need assistance in articulating the benefits of Design 1 to our product team, who are inclined towards Design 2. How can I effectively communicate the value of a simpler, more concise design that aligns with user preferences?
Thank you for your time and expertise! I look forward to your feedback and suggestions.



You would probably want to do that with research and testing data, at least to start with.
Keep in mind that what the designer thinks is simpler isn't necessarily what the end-users think is simpler. To avoid the same bias that the product team has, first you must also remove your own bias towards a particular solution.
That's the evidence-based and data-driven approach to design decisions, and it is usually the most valuable information you can offer to the product team in your role as a researcher/designer.
